# How do I prevent Django from sending certain information to ADMIN when errors occur

Tags: django, debugging, logging, production

My goal is to filter out some of the information going out via email when an error occurs in Django (production). if Debug=False Django sends an email to admin containing 3 areas: the Traceback, the Request and app Settings.

The current default Django logging works for me, I'm only asking about the best way to filter out information under Settings from going out via email?

Thanks

Comment: There's a whole section in the documentation on [filtering error reports](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/error-reporting/#filtering-error-reports).

Comment: i saw this section, however it did not help specifically with what I need

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I suggest you demonstrate how you have attempted to solve this so far and why it's not working.